# Spring Boot JUnit H2 test failing in Gitlab

Tags: spring, junit, gitlab, h2, boot

I have some Spring Boot JUnit test that run successfully local.  However when I commit to my GitLab repo I'm getting the following exception when executing my gradle test.

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at     AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException at AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException at AbstractSchemaValidator.java:129
```

I looked at the validator source and it appears an exception is thrown if the tableInformation is `null`.  I noticed that the exception occurs before the H2 `data.sql` is executed.  So there is some validation that occurs that is producing the exception in GitLab but not local.

Here are my application.properties:

```
# Spring DataSource Properties
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password

# Spring JPA Properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-    strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl


# Hibernate Properties
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect``
```

Also I'm using the same build.gradle for both environments.
Has anyone ran into this issue before or seen anything close?

I've tried changing the properties and the CI/CD yaml but the results are the same.  Also I have not build failures in either environment.

Comment: Please post the **full stacktrace** not some partial snippet.